# How to show recylerview items behind the bottom navigation view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottomnavigationview, rounded-corners, cornerradius

Hello i have a bottom navigation view which has corner radius from topLeft 30dp and same for the topRight and i have a recylerview which has to be above bottom navigation ,but what i want that still above the bottom navigation view the recyler items can be seen from that corner of the bottom navigation

as you can see in the bellow screen shot the corner of the bottom navigation dosent looks good i want that the items can be seen behind that empty space with recyclerview above the bottom navigation

**Update 1 // after get solution from the comment**

**bottom_navigation_view.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_navigation_style"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:itemIconSize="30dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation">


</com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```

**bottom_navigation_style.xml** // Drawble for giving the color and radius to the bottom navigation view

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/primary_dark_grey"/>
    <corners android:radius="100dp"/>

</shape>
```

**fragment_profile.xml**

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/postRecyclerViewProfile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:overScrollMode="never" />
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewHome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />
```

**Update 2**

**post_item_container_profile.xml** // layout for profle recylerview

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp">
    
        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey"
            app:cardElevation="1dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="4dp"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCorner">
    
            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagePost"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCorner" />
    
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try this once `app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: nope not working

Comment: what happens when you remove `android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation_view"` ?let the recycler behind the bottom navigation bar n try once @Vasant

Comment: `android:layout_above` this is causing issue in layout

Comment: if i remove layout_above="bottom_navigation_view" it solves my current issue becuae than the fragment container takes the entier space , but when the last item will arrive it cant be seen properly becuase the list gonna end and the item will be behind bottom navigation view

Comment: then give `recyclerview` some paddingBottom which should be equal to bottomnavigationbar height

Comment: actually the bottom navigation hieght is wrap_content how can i do it

Comment: here is a screen shot of what happens if i remove layout_above and reach to the end of the list https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EraLkowX-aAxxbTDgZ1KRVBh8nNTPh1c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try to make your custom view or use any custom view for bottom navigation, which are able to give curves with background color

Comment: @DeePanShu but will it be usefull for multiple size device will it be like wrap_content can u tell me how to do that

Comment: @VasantRaval give this paddingbottom `"?android:attr/actionBarSize"`

Comment: thank you so much for the help i cant belevie it it worked without any hastles

Comment: @Wini ok im sorry after get your solution i wanted that the bottom navigation showuld be like the video i have share the link in the end and i also have aded your line of code it worked well with the previous bottom nav but with this there is a black epmty space when the recylerview is scrolled up but it fix when i sroll down , also the last item with this has slight behind the bottom nav

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IY5kS-fuhBaGmSHGGQkrwUiizdoE4TlM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i have updated the code to

Comment: @VasantRaval can you add your recyclerview row layout

Comment: ok i have aded both recylervew

Comment: @VasantRaval i want to see the child row layout of recyclerview...the layout which we inflate in adapter

Comment: i will remove the previous code becuase the the layout that inflate the recylerview is big it will be more confusing should i remove the old code if you want

Comment: Yes @VasantRaval just remove like SS and activity_main code only rest keep as such

Comment: ok i have aded thr code

Comment: so you are having issue in `post_item_container_profile` layout ?

Comment: yes the last item is slightly behind the bootom nav

Comment: @VasantRaval i think this is causing issue `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"` in MaterialCardView

Comment: i change the material card view dp from 10 to 9 and also dd the same wth recyclervew but it dosent solved it

Comment: do u think its fine

Comment: just only remove that `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"` from materialcardview and dont do anything in recyclerview layout

Comment: if you want some view to be above another one just put it below in your xml file

Comment: no i cant do that it will reduce the size between all  the images

Comment: removing the top margin will affects the images

Comment: i felt the remaining problem is causing issue only because of hardcoded value ...@VasantRaval

Comment: ok , thank you so much for your t means a lot for the bottom nav  part